# save canvas as pdf on specific path

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pdf, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to save canvas as pdf **on specific path**.
I can get download option using given code, but I did not get proper way to save pdf on specific path. 
Can anyone help me to save canvas as pdf on specific path?
 Here is my javascript code.

```
function saveAsPdf() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false});
    var customerId = getParameterByName("intCustomerId");
    var image = canvas.toDataURL();
    image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '')
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Oh how I wish it were possible but you are restricted by security. We can't have web pages just saving wherever they like that would cause all sorts of mayhem. You have to set the browser's download directory to the location you want and only  the client can do that.

Comment: Thanks, Do we have any other way to do this? My client want it any how...

Comment: Depends on the browser. You can get extra permissions for extensions including some sandboxed file system access ( or more I have never looked into it that deeply) but it will require that you create an extension and that the client accepts the requested access (they can still block you if they wish, after all it is their private property you are asking to access)

Comment: Thanks everybody. Your suggestions cleared my concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that directly we can't save pdf to specific path.So I used another way to save it.

```
    string tempFileName = "temp.png";
    tempPathToSave = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(tempFileName);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempPathToSave, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
        fs.Close();
    }
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
    doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
   using (XImage img = XImage.FromFile(tempPathToSave))
   {
     XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
     xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
     doc.Save(pathToSave);
     doc.Close(); 
   }
    if (File.Exists(tempPathToSave))
       File.Delete(tempPathToSave);
```

Simply, saved canvas to temparary image and converted image into PDF. I used PDFSharp.dll for this.